# MYSQL query to call most recent value using timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-order-by, grafana

I am using grafana and I need to call the most recent value of the adl_ex_ante_price where the value is not null (as shown below) using a query. I do have the related timestamp for each row.

[image: Table layout]

The code I have tried is depicted below:

```
SELECT
  gas_date AS "time",
  adl_ex_ante_price
FROM gas_market_prices
ORDER BY gas_date
WHERE
  NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the latest non-`null` price, you can filter, `order by` and `limit`:

```
select gas_date, adl_ex_ante_price 
from gas_market_prices 
where adl_ex_ante_price is not null
order by gas_date desc limit 1
```